# Access Enunciate docs through running application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, enunciate

I am trying to generate enunciate docs for my application. At the moment, I am able to generate the documentation successfully by running `mvn clean install`. In order to access the generated docs, I need to manually open the index.html file but I am not able to access the docs via running application on localhost:8000.

This is my pom.xml file:

```
<build>
        <finalName>abc</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
             <plugin>
                <groupId>com.webcohesion.enunciate</groupId>
                <artifactId>enunciate-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.13.2</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>docs</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <configFile>src/main/enunciate/enunciate.xml</configFile>
                            <docsDir>${project.build.directory}/docs/api/</docsDir>
                            <docsSubdir>v1</docsSubdir>
                            <addJavaClientSourcesToTestClasspath>false</addJavaClientSourcesToTestClasspath>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

This is my enunciate.xml file:

```
<enunciate slug="abc-rest" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://enunciate.webcohesion.com/schemas/enunciate-2.11.0.xsd">
  <title>ABC</title>

  <modules>
    <jackson disabled="true"/>
    <jaxb disabled="true"/>
    <jaxws disabled="true"/>
    <swagger disabled="true" />
    <docs disableRestMountpoint="false"/>
  </modules>

</enunciate>
```